# Generating statistics from Git repository for subdirs

Tags: git, logging, statistics

I have tried googling looking for some sort of GIT analyzer, but I haven't found anything.

I have a Git project, with some subdirectories (each of them is a project itself). I need some information from each of them:
- Last commit/commits
- The list of people who committed
- Possibly some sort of stats on commits per author, commit day/week, ....

Every info is needed to be reachable through command line response, or http ( for example as a web service )

Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Some options?

1) Have you seen the type of statistics that GitHub offers out of the box? Like the [pulse](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pulse) or all the other [stats](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/graphs).

2) http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/, never used it but found it while googling the API the other day.

3) In my company we did our own analysis page on top of github pages using simply the [GitHub activity api](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/)

If you don't use github only options 2) is at your grasp. Parsing a `log` is not that hard if you can't find anything else.